# Is this the expected EvaluationMonitor behavior with NDSolve with Method->"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta"

Tags: differential-equations

It appears that EvaluationMonitor is not being called as expected, but only when I am using SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta.

Here is a stripped down example to illustrate.

Forces in Hamilton's equations just to test:

```
fVec[positions_?ArrayQ] := positions - RotateRight[positions]
```

This works just fine:

```
{q, p} = NDSolveValue[{pvec'[t] == fVec[qvec[t]], 
   qvec'[t] == pvec[t], pvec[0] == ConstantArray[0, 10], 
   qvec[0] == Range[10]
   }, {qvec, pvec}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta", 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, "PositionVariables" -> {qvec[t]}}]
Plot[q[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Let's put an evaluation monitor inside:

It appears that the EvaluationMonitor is only sowing the initial event and one other:

```
    {{q, p}, reaped} = Reap[
      NDSolveValue[
{
pvec'[t] == fVec[qvec[t]], 
qvec'[t] == pvec[t], 
        pvec[0] == ConstantArray[0, 10], 
qvec[0] == Range[10]
        }, {qvec, pvec}, {t, 0, 10}, 
       Method -> {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta", 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, "PositionVariables" -> {qvec[t]}},
       EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{t, qvec[t], Norm[qvec[t] - Range[10]]}]
       ]
      ]
```

Let's use WhenEvent to test whether intermediate evaluations are made:

```
{{q, p}, reaped} = Reap[
  NDSolveValue[{pvec'[t] == fVec[qvec[t]], qvec'[t] == pvec[t], 
    pvec[0] == ConstantArray[0, 10], qvec[0] == Range[10],

    WhenEvent[Norm[qvec[t] - Range[10]] > 20, "StopIntegration"]

    }, {qvec, pvec}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta", 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, "PositionVariables" -> {qvec[t]}},
   EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{t, qvec[t], Norm[qvec[t] - Range[10]]}]
   ]
```

It appears that EvaluationMonitor was only called with WhenEvent triggered something.

As a sanity check, let's remove the Method:

```
{{q, p}, reaped} = Reap[
  NDSolveValue[{pvec'[t] == fVec[qvec[t]], qvec'[t] == pvec[t], 
    pvec[0] == ConstantArray[0, 10], qvec[0] == Range[10],
    WhenEvent[Norm[qvec[t] - Range[10]] > 20, "StopIntegration"]
    }, {qvec, pvec}, {t, 0, 10},
   EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{t, qvec[t], Norm[qvec[t] - Range[10]]}]
   ]
  ]
```

Yup, EvaluationMonitor is being called at each evaluation.

Is this a bug, or am I missing somethning?

Comment: And `StepMonitor` works as expected. The behavior is similar in _v5.0_, so if this is a bug, it's an old one.